# Not much to this one, once you've understood it

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence, letters

A O E A O T F L A T O A _

R R A C O A O M R Y Y E _

Fill in the missing two letters.

**Notes**

Please explain why, in the context you have discovered, these are the only two possible answers and there is no room for doubt.

Comment: Hi, if you down vote please explain so that I can improve the question. Feedback is always welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but maybe the downvoter doesn't like the fact that you just put 2 cryptograms into a puzzle, without a story or any hints to get a clue how (or with what cipher) to decrypt it. (Although I don't know yet if this puzzle is more of a cryptogram or a letter-sequence that hasn't got a decrypted text)

Comment: Apologies - I have been trying to find the best tags. I removed *cryptogram* and added *letters*. I think I have the right ones now.

Comment: Is it the same rule for both strings or do they each have their own pattern?

Comment: @EngineerToast - There is only one pattern and both strings fit into it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> E

and

> U

And the reason is ...

> Each letter is the last letter of the NATO phonetic alphabet, in order. So we have alphA, bravO, charliE, deltA etc. The missing letters are for Mike and Zulu

Comment: Yes, that is the perfect answer.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Nice one!